# Triggered rule in drupal to create user account automatically

Tags: php, drupal

I am working on drupal6 to develop a web application for office automation. I have an Employee content type. Each time I create an employee content, an account should be created with user name, and email id taken from fields of employee content. I've searched for the same on net, and found few solutions written completely in php, but i couldn't find how this can be done through **rules-> triggered rules** option in drupal(shown in figure). What entries should be provided in these username,email fields? I should get these from the content that I just created before triggering this. I tried exploring "Replacement patterns for saved content" option provided like [node:field_name], but no luck. Can someone help me with this?

None of the following (which are listed in "Token replacement patterns -> Replacement patterns for saved content") are working

[node:field_emp_name-formatted] Formatted and filtered text

[node:field_emp_name-raw]   Raw, unfiltered text Warning: Token value contains raw user input.

[node:field_emp_mail-formatted] Formatted email address

[node:field_emp_mail-raw]   Raw email address Warning: Token value contains raw user input.

Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: First - I started doing this with a project of mine and then realized it was twice as efficient, took 1/2 the space and processing and time if you just create them as new users directly and give them a new role as "employee", then either add the fields you need to the User bundle or use relation/references for separate content linked to the employee.  Second thing is - I completely forgot.  I'll think of it eventually lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suddenly started working for the following field values

User name: [node:field_emp_name-formatted]

User's E-mail: [node:field_emp_mail-raw]

I think it does not take "formatted" field for E-mail, since it has anchor tags, etc.,